# How to sort data by rating with Aws Lambda using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, backend

I have a db on Dynamodb. And writing some user scores to db. Also I have a lambda function which wrote it with nodejs. I want to get first 10 users who have most points. How could I scan this users?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`Max()` in NoSQL is much trickier than in SQL. And it doesn't really scale - if you want very high scalability on achieving this let me know, but let's get back to the question.

Assuming your table looks like:

```
User
----------
userId - hashKey
score
...
```

Add a dummy `category` attribute to your table, which will be constant (for example value "A"). Create the index:

```
category - hash key
score - sort key
```

Query this index by hash key "A" in reserve order in order to get results much faster than a `scan`. But this scales to max 10GB (max partition size, all data being in same partition). Also make sure you project only needed attributes for this index, in order to save space.

You can go up to 30GB for example, by setting 3 categories ("A", "B", "C"), executing 3 queries and merge programatically the results. This will affect performance a bit, but still better than a full scan.

**EDIT**

```
var params = {
  TableName: 'MyTableName',
  Limit: 10,
  // Set ScanIndexForward to false to display most recent entries first
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  KeyConditionExpression: 'category = : category',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':category': {
      S: 'category',
    },
  },
};

dynamo.query(params, function(err, data) {
  // handle data
});
```

source: https://www.debassociates.com/blog/query-dynamodb-table-from-a-lambda-function-with-nodejs-and-apex-up/

Comment: You haven't provided the most useful information here, which is to show the OP how to query a particular index in reverse order (by using the `ScanIndexForward` attribute). Your information on the 10GB limit is worthless as the OP explicitly said he is only interested in the top 10 items. Considering DynamoDB's item max size of 400KB, it's impossible that 10 items reach the 10GB limit. Providing information on how to set the `Limit` here would be very useful. Your answer is quite incomplete, therefore the downvote.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi I was referring to the partition size, not item size. The query is very basic and it depends and the data and environment, but I can provide a generic one if needed.

Comment: DynamoDB will manage to store items even if the partition has reached 10GB by repartioning again. This is quite a complex topic which is out of the scope for this question

Comment: Removing my downvote as you have edited the answer with proper details.